# Tic Tac Toe Error Python

Tags: python, indexing, tic-tac-toe

I'm having an indexing error with the following line of code, could someone please tell me what is wrong and why hopefully fix the error

```
for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
    if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
        winner = board[row[0]]
        return winner
```

The Full Code is:

```
def winner(board, EMPTY):
    #If you have won
    TIE = "TIE"
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((1, 2, 3),
                   (4, 5, 6),
                   (7, 8, 9),
                   (1, 4, 7),
                   (2, 5, 8),
                   (3, 6, 9),
                   (1, 5, 9),
                   (3, 5, 7))

    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner
```

Comment: way too much code. We need `WAYS_TO_WIN` and `board` only, not the whole program. Also your indentation is off for the top section

Comment: Sorry I just changed it, This is my first post. Is it ok now?

Comment: there's still a lot of excess. What's `new_board`?

Comment: it just creates a new board.

Comment: def new_board(NUM_SQUARES, EMPTY):
    #Create A New Board 
    
    board = [] 
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES): 
        board.append(EMPTY) 
    return board

Comment: *Probably* (based on code I can't see) the issue is that board is indexed from 0, not from 1. Your WAYS TO WIN is indexed from 1.

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: It works now! all i had to do was take 1 away from all of the numbers in ways to win! thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `NUM_SQUARES == 9` and python is 0 indexed, the highest index you can access from the board is board[8] (which is the ninth place on the board).

so take 1 away from all of the numbers in `WAYS_TO_WIN` and it should be fine.

In more detail - the board is indexed from 0 through to 8, a total of 9 places. (0 being the first, 8 being the ninth). `WAYS_TO_WIN` has a minimum value of 1, and a max of 9. 1 is equivalent to the second place on the board, and 9 would be equivalent to the non-existent 10th place, which causes the error.